# Buttons and checkboxed in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, button, checkbox

I am trying to have a checkbox ("remember") that is used for selecting if I want to print all of the objects or just the ones that reached their sell price (auction site). So basically if the box is checked we only write the ones where the price is reached. If it's not checked we write all of them.

When I try to run it the program complains about the OnClick="checkValidated(); that I have on my button and refuses to run completely. The error I get tells me nothing:
Compiler Error Message: CS1026: ) expected, since I can't see a need for another ")".

ViewAuctionsButtonUnchecked_Click and ViewAuctionsButtonChecked_Click are in filename.aspx.cs and both work. Any ideas on what I should change?

```
<input id="remember" name="remember" type="checkbox" onclick="validate()" />


<asp:Button ID="ViewAuctionsButton" OnClick="checkValidated();" Text="Visa"
            CssClass="" runat="server" />


    function validate() {
        if (document.getElementById('remember').checked) {
            alert("checked");
        } else {
            alert("You didn't check it! Let me check it for you.");
        }
    }

    function checkValidated() {
        if (document.getElementById('remember').checked) {
            ViewAuctionsButtonUnchecked_Click;
        } else {
            ViewAuctionsButtonChecked_Click;
        }
    }
```

Before I had to put in the checkbox, the code looked like this (and worked):

```
<asp:Button ID="ViewAuctionsButton" OnClick="ViewAuctionsButtonUnchecked_Click;" Text="Visa"
            CssClass="" runat="server" />
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove the ";"

If you want to run a server-side event handler you need this

```
<asp:Button ID="ViewAuctionsButton" OnClick="checkValidated"
```

if you (your case) want to fire a javascript event you need this

```
<asp:Button ID="ViewAuctionsButton" OnClientClick="checkValidated()"
```

that renders as

```
<input type="submit" name="ViewAuctionsButton" onclick="checkValidated();" id="ViewAuctionsButton" />
```

Comment: While this makes the checkValidated run, it won't run the ViewAuctionsButtonUnchecked_Click.

Comment: You are a little confused, you cannot fire a serverside event handler from javascript. Read again my answer, OnClick fires a serverside eventhandler OnClientClick fires a javascript event.
You must decide if you want manage your logic server or client side.
For example you could use onclick="MySERVERSIDEEvent" and there you can test if checkbox is checked or not.